# Understanding generated C code. How to exchange arguments and return values?

Tags: function, dll, simulink

I have a beginner question. I am new to programming and I generated my first C Code from Simulink successfully. But I don't understand how the Input and Output pass the function. How this function works? It has no arguments and no return values but provides a calculation. How the main program interacts with this function?

firstTest.c generates initialize, step and terminate functions. Step is the calculation.

```
 // firstTest.c
 void firstTest_step(void)
 {    
   Test_Y.Out = 2.0 + Test_U.In;
 }
```

firstTest.h generates the corresponding header files to firstTest.c

```
// firstTest.h
extern void firstTest_step(void);
```

My plan is to use this functionality somehow in my own c# application. The solution will probably contain pinvoke to handle unmanaged code. Because I don't understand this function I have tried to play a little bit around and found out that it is possible to customize the step function, so that the Code generator produce the step function from the same model in a way that I see arguments, which I can work with! (I don't even know if this is necessary?). So the second Test looks like this:

```
// secondTest.c
void secondTest_step(real_T In, real_T *Out)
    {     
      *Out = 2.0 + In;
    }
```

The generated header file to this:

```
// secondTest.h
extern void secondTest_step(real_T In, real_T *Out);
```

Now, Simulink provides the possibility to generate a C DLL. So this is what I tried successfully, I had only to modify the header with __declspec according to mathworks/simulink documentations. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
// The DLL in which __declspec(dllexport) is a custom modification
__declspec(dllexport) void secondTest(real_T In, real_T *Out)
```

Is secondTest the right approach to exchange data with an extern application, that wants to use the simple step functionality (out = in + 2)? My biggest confusion is still about the void-void function. I can understand that you can pass arguments through a function with pointers too, instead of 'normal' arguments. But I fail to see how the generated function firstTest.c works? It has no pointers and no values as arguments, only the calculation without a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of firstTest, the input structure Test_U and the output structure Test_Y are global, so they can be set from your wrapper/integration code.

The default settings allow for generating a stand-alone exe and so these global structure are declared and defined. So typically the interface of the generated is customized. That is why Simulink offers all the options to customize the function definiton itsel, but also the way an individual signal appears in the code.

Comment: I think your short respond answered my main questions. So there are simply different storage classes and 'extern' variables can be used by all functions in the program. 
But what do you mean by wrapper/integration code exactly? Is model.h the wrapper? Or the generated code around the specific function? For example: The generated logic of the subsystem is the same, but depending on the model (plant, Input etc.) you get a different code around step function? Is this statement correct?

Comment: Typically, you do not generate a stand-alone executable, but use the code in a larger framework. Calling the generated code from the existing software, is what I mean by the wrapper/integration code.In many cases this code is also generated - that is why Simulink Coder offers all kinds of ways to generate more files or change the ert_main.c file.